# Print via terminal without usblp

Tags: linux, printer, cups

I need to print in an Epson TM-U220PD model M188D for receipts (without cups support), I used to write in a terminal [text] > /dev/lp0 but
now usblp is deprecated. I can use this printer enabling the usblp kernel module, but this action disable cups.

There's other way to print, maybe using CUPS? How can I find the new path to the printer?

Answer (score 0):

CUPS comes with versions of the SysV `lp` and BSD `lpr` commands, both of which are able to print text files or data from stdin.